# Objective c: drawing a png on the screen (UIImage inside a UIImageView)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgimage

I'm writing a brickbreaker and I'm creating a class that will draw all elements (balls, bricks and paddle) on the screen.

I tried to put toghether some code taken by the official doc:

```
    -(id) drawWithGC: (CGContextRef) myContext andCGRect: (CGRect) myContextRect andPath: (const char *) filename
{
    CGImageRef image;
    CGDataProviderRef provider;
    CFStringRef path;
    CFURLRef url;

    path = CFStringCreateWithCString (NULL, filename, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, path, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, NO);
    CFRelease(path);
    provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithURL (url);
    CFRelease (url);
    image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider (provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGDataProviderRelease (provider);
    CGContextDrawImage (myContext, myContextRect, image);
    CGImageRelease (image);

    UIImage *finalImage = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithCGImage:image];
    UIImageView *finalImageView = [[UIImage alloc] initWithImage:finalImage];

    return finalImageView;

}
```

I can't test this because my others class aren't finished but is it "conceptually" right? 
Otherwise do you have some sample I can test to draw images UIImages into UIImageView et retrive, for example center.x and center.y position?

Thanks

Comment: That is done before you wrote...open you eyes before talk! ;-)

Comment: Well done.. You have started to accept answers.. Wish you luck.. I wish every one come forward to answer your questions.. And you take pleasure to answer others' questions.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

- Assuming you are bundling graphics for your images within your app bundle, why not just use [UIImage imagedName: @"Brick.png"] to load images?
- You are leaking a UIImage and UIImageView, which suggests you may need to revisit basic memory management documentation.